# Q:How can I include the js file in wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress theme and It's work good.
Every things are working , images , bootstrap CDN , styke.css . but I have a big problem! my Javascript file is not working!!!!!
I write the JS codes in other file and I inclde the file in header.php file but It's not working.
If you have a true answer pleas help me.

Comment: *it does not work* is not an error message, you have to be more precise : do you get an error ? is the script loaded ?

Comment: No, I don't give the error but Js file is not working.

Comment: can you provide your code with the expected result and the actual result ? also please show the code you used into header.php to add your js file

Comment: This is the documented way to include Javascript files into your WordPress theme: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: I added this code in the header.php file:         <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo(' template_url '); ?>tjs.js"></script>

Comment: Where I write these codes? In witch file?

Answer (score 1):

Within your WordPress **child theme** functions.php file you would add the function:

```
wp_enqueue_script()
```

Example:

```
 function add_child_theme_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/child-theme-scripts-folder/your-script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.0, true);
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_child_theme_scripts' );
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#scripts

Comment: Glad to help out. Mark as correct if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your function file and edit it.

```
//Funtion that add script in header
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'unique-script-name-id', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script-name.js', array(), '', false);
}

//Add action hook to call function
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a child theme, do not modify the parent theme files.